# Keep track of TV shows

Tags: linux, media-manager

I'm looking for a simple, KISS software to keep track of the tv shows I watch.

Something simple to check an episode when I saw it. Features like a calendar to notify me when a new episode is out would be appreciated but not necessary.

It must run locally on Linux, but can be multi platform. I'm not interested in an Android app.

Comment: A bit short description :) Maybe you could [edit] your post and at least include which OS(es) it should run on? If an Android app would be acceptable, you might e.g. find one in my list of [Series browser & tracker](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_information_tv#group_862) apps.

Comment: I edited my post, sorry. I sometimes forget not everybody runs linux...

Comment: *LOL* understandable. I've heard there's also something called "Windows" – but I opened the "door" and though it out #D (MS free zone here)

Comment: Would tvcmd work? (http://tvcmd.horlux.org/)

Comment: It seems to be ok. I'm going to test it right away. CLI programs are fine, but if you have a GUI one, I wouldn't mind either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [DuckieTV](http://schizoduckie.github.io/DuckieTV/?from=duckie.tv&/):

- is multi-platform and runs on Linux,
- has a calendar and shows when the shows air,
- enables you to tick your shows as watched,
- connects to torrent, if you want it to.

Might be worth a look.